# Ensure that the parent bash script does not exit even if the child script exits

Tags: bash

I have two shell scripts one is the parentscript and another is the child script.

**Code for parent script**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

bash /home/ubuntu/test/deploy.sh

echo "I can still do this"
```

**Code for child script**

```
python -c \
"""
from db_wrapper import db
import sys

query_string = \
'select * from pipeline_release_status \
where release_deployed_at is null' 

release_status = db.run_query(db.get_environment(), query_string)

if not release_status:
    sys.exit(1)
"""

if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
    echo "No release to deploy"
    exit 1
fi
```

Regardless if child script exits or not i don't want the parent script to exit ever so i would always want the `echo "i can still do this"` statement to always get executed. However in my case if child script exits then the parent gets exited too.

How do i prevent that?

Comment: Stop using `set -e` until you understand what it does and why it does what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the first line of the parent script, you have `set -euo pipefail`. The `-e` option makes it so the script exits if any of the commands ran fails (exit status different from 0).

You can either remove the `-e` option, leaving you with `set -uo pipefail`, or make sure the child script always exits with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `set -euo pipefail` from the parent script.